# Iterate through a Clojure Instaparse Tree

Tags: parsing, clojure, tree, nodes

```
(def grammar
        "
        <root> = line*
        <line> = START REST
        <START> = #'[0-9]{4} '
        <REST> = NA | NZ | DATETIME
        <NA> = 'Nicht angemeldet '
        <NZ> = 'Nicht zugelassen '
        <DATETIME> = TAG ZEIT 
        <TAG> = 'Montag ' | 'Dienstag '
        <ZEIT> = #'[0-9]{1}.*Uhr '
        ")

(defn changed-x [tree]
  (postwalk
    (fn [node]
      (if (and (vector? node) (= (first node) :line))
        [:line (-> node rest 10)]
        node))
    tree))

(defn -main
  [& args]
;; Create the tree and save it to "tree" with a function (not included here) 
but it works
      (def tree (test-title-parser title-grammar-1 In))
;; Change the tree so every line just becomes "10" hardcoded in the changed-x function
      (changed-x tree)
;; print the tree
      (println tree)
    )
```

this is a (small) test string to parse:
**1017 Montag 13-14:30Uhr 1026 Nicht zugelassen**

```
i want this to happen:
1017 Montag 13-14:30 Uhr 
1026 Nicht zugelassen
```

Just a tiny CR-Enter at the end of every line, or printed to the console so i can Redirect the Output to a file.
I would love to have tabs between the number and the text. So i can paste the result to Excel and it gets in 2 seperate fields per line.

```
my tree Looks like this 
(1017  Montag  13-14:30Uhr 1026 Nicht zugelassen .................. )
```

i put <> arround all the stuff that i dont Need.

Now please just solve this last tiny bit of the damn puzzle for me (begging) as i put hours in understanding instaparse and the way it works just to find out it does seperate my string correctly but bringing me 0% closer to what i really want. There has to be some sort of success atleast once a freakn week. srsly... i could do that in minutes with 4 different languages, a damn for loop and a variable with the string is what i need.

I tried to understand your function:
How is that to be read? What exactly are the nodes? Everything I put on the left side of my grammar? What does the -> do here? Never seen it used this way and why do we have the []-Brackets? What does the last node do?

```
  (if (and (vector? node) (= (first node) :line))
    [:line (-> node rest 10)]
    node))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to provide explanation without complete grammar. Let's say, it is defined like this:

```
(def xyz
  (insta/parse
    "S = A+
     A = X Y Z
     X = 'x'+
     Y = 'y'+
     Z = 'z'+"))
```

It will basically match regex `#"(x+y+z+)+"`. Now let's try to create parse tree from input:

```
(def t (xyz "xyyzzzxxxyyz"))    
t ; => [:S [:A [:X "x"] [:Y "y" "y"] [:Z "z" "z" "z"]] [:A [:X "x" "x" "x"] [:Y "y" "y"] [:Z "z"]]]
```

There are two parts of the question - how to modify this tree and how to use it in Enlive.

### Enlive part of the answer

[Enlive](https://github.com/cgrand/enlive) is a selector-based templating library for Clojure. To use this tree for templating, you need to rename keys `:S`, `:A`, `:X`, `:Y`, `:Z` to some tags. Let's replace them to `:div`, `:p`, `:h1`, `:h2` and `:h3` respectively. For such key renaming there is [postwalk-replace](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk/postwalk-replace) function:

```
(use 'clojure.walk)

(def tags (postwalk-replace {:S :div :A :span :X :h1 :Y :h2 :Z :h3} t))
tags ; => [:div [:span [:h1 "x"] [:h2 "y" "y"] [:h3 "z" "z" "z"]] [:span [:h1 "x" "x" "x"] [:h2 "y" "y"] [:h3 "z"]]]
```

`tags` vector is ready to be used in Enlive:

```
(use 'net.cgrand.enlive-html)

(html tags) ; => ({:tag :div, :attrs {}, :content ({:tag :span, :attrs {}, :content ({:tag :h1, :attrs {}, :content ("x")} {:tag :h2, :attrs {}, :content ("y" "y")} {:tag :h3, :attrs {}, :content ("z" "z" "z")})} {:tag :span, :attrs {}, :content ({:tag :h1, :attrs {}, :content ("x" "x" "x")} {:tag :h2, :attrs {}, :content ("y" "y")} {:tag :h3, :attrs {}, :content ("z")})})})
```

### Tree modification part of the answer

To modify tree values for `:X` nodes you could use [postwalk](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk/postwalk) function:

```
(defn changed-x [tree f]
  (postwalk
    (fn [node]
      (if (and (vector? node) (= (first node) :X))
        [:X (-> node rest f)]
        node))
    tree))

(changed-x t count) ; => [:S [:A [:X 1] [:Y "y" "y"] [:Z "z" "z" "z"]] [:A [:X 3] [:Y "y" "y"] [:Z "z"]]]
```

In example above for all `:X` nodes children (multiple strings `"x"`) were changed by single number - their count. And finally if you want to discard all nodes except of `:X`, you can use [tree-seq](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/tree-seq) function:

```
(defn filter-by-key [tree node-key]
  (->> tree
       (tree-seq vector? identity)
       (filter #(and
                  (vector? %)
                  (= (first %) node-key)))))

(filter-by-key t :X) ; => ([:X "x"] [:X "x" "x" "x"])
```

Comment: i tryed for 2 hours (with the help you provided) and still cant loop it.

Please look at the tree:

`=> [:S [:A [:X "WHY"] [:Y "y" "y"] [:Z "z" "z" "z"] [:A [:X "NOT"] [:Y "y" "y"] [:Z "z" "z" "z"]] `

****, i just want to print:
**=> WHY
=> NOT**

Comment: `(filter-by-key your-tree :X)` gives `([:X "WHY"] [:X "NOT"])`. If you want get "WHY" and "NOT" strings - you can just use `(map second (filter-by-key your-tree :X))`. It will yield `("WHY" "NOT")`. Is this not enough for processing?

Comment: By the way, you can also use `changed-x` function for printing: `(changed-x your-tree #(apply println %))`. It will print WHY and NOT in separate lines and then return the tree.

Comment: demotivated as one can be... however i retyped the complete question to make myself clearer. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution was really close. The main problem was with the grammar. You have putted `<>` for each non-terminal symbols. Because of that all semantics is lost and the tree `("1017 " "Montag " "13-14:30Uhr " "1026 " "Nicht zugelassen ")` consists only from terminal nodes.

Consider next grammar:

```
(def grammar
    "
    <root> = line*
    line = START REST
    <START> = #'[0-9]{4} '
    <REST> = NA | NZ | DATETIME
    <NA> = 'Nicht angemeldet '
    <NZ> = 'Nicht zugelassen '
    <DATETIME> = TAG ZEIT 
    <TAG> = 'Montag ' | 'Dienstag '
    <ZEIT> = #'[0-9]{1}.*Uhr '
    ") ; Note "line" non-terminal - it's not wrapped now
```

As result, tree will look like `([:line "1017 " "Montag " "13-14:30Uhr "] [:line "1026 " "Nicht zugelassen "])`. Now, the slightly more general version of `changed-x`:

```
(defn tree-apply [tree tree-key f]
  (postwalk
    (fn [node]
      (if (and (vector? node) (= (first node) tree-key))
        [tree-key (-> node rest f)]
        node))
    tree))
```

Basically, hard-coded `:X` keyword changed to be parameter and function was renamed to more meaningful name.

And finally, usage which will print tab-separated terms:

```
(require '[clojure.string :as s])

(tree-apply t :line #(->> % (s/join "\t") println))
1017    Montag  13-14:30Uhr 
1026    Nicht zugelassen
```

**Some explanations**. `tree-apply` is the function that returns updated version of the tree with altered nodes given by `tree-key`. It works with the format where node is a vector with first element being node key, rest - either leafs of the tree or child nodes:

```
[:a [:b "c"] "d" [:e]]
```

Here `:a`, `:b`, `:e` are node keys; `:b`, `:e` are children of `:a`; `"c"`, `"d"` are leafs. For next tree

```
[:root [:a] [:a "a"] [:b] [:a 1] [:c ...]]
```

`(tree-apply t :a f)` will take to account nodes `[:a]`, `[:a "a"]` and `[:a 1]` not touching `:b` and `:c`. Function `f` takes as parameter "internals" of the node. It would be `()` (empty sequence) for first node `[:a]`, `("a")` for `[:a "a"]` and `(1)` for `[:a 1]`. Result of `f` is placed to newly built tree, so resulting tree will look like:

```
[:root [:a (f)] [:a (f '("a"))] [:b] [:a (f '(1))] [:c ...]]
```

This function can provide side effects as in example above. Function

```
#(->> % (s/join "\t") println)
```

is shortcut to

```
(fn [coll] (println (s/join "\t" coll)))
```

Basically, it accepts sequence, joins it to string separated by tab character and prints resulting string in new line.